# ASPX Master Pages with DIV to be side by side

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Need help. 
I cannot figure out why I cannot place div side by side in the child .aspx of master page.

The code works if I hardcode the style like this

```
<div id="pagemiddleleft" style="float:left;">
```

But when I move the style into the CSS file, the div's refuse to sit side by side.

Below is the child code

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div id="pagetop">
</div>
<div id="pagemiddle">
        <div id="pagemiddleleft">111111
        </div>
        <div id="pagemiddlecenter">111111
        </div>
        <div id="pagemiddleright">111111
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<div id="pagebottom">
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Below is an extraction of the Master Page

```
 <div class="page">
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Below is the CSS portion for the child aspx page

```
#pagemiddleleft {
float: left; background-color: #FFFF00;}

#pagemiddlecenter {
float: left; background-color: #00FFFF;}

#pagemiddleright {
float: right; background-color: #FF00FF;}
```

Comment: Can you please show the rendered code, are you sure that the css is loaded ? do you have this online ?

Comment: Are you really sure that the css is loaded?

Comment: I don't have it online. The styling looks ok except for the DIVs inside the contentplaceholder portion.

Comment: Guys, thank you for helping. I just want to highlight that if I were to do a simple HTML page with the DIV tags and the CSS file. I don't have any problems. It is only when I use the Visual Studio and use the Master Page that this problem occurs

Comment: I noticed something interesting. When I tried on Chrome and used the Inspect Element. It shows all the DIV tags in the Content page does not match any CSS stylesheet elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this master page layout

**Master Page**

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <style type="text/css">
        div.page
        {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            background:#ffc;
        }
        div#main
        {
            float: left;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        div#page-left
        {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            background:orange;
        }
        div#page-right
        {
            float: right;
            width: 20%;
            background:green;
        }
        div#page-middle
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 60%;
            background:blue;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <div id="main">
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div id="page-left">
                   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="leftContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div id="page-middle">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="middleContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                <div id="page-right">
                 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="rightContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Content Page**

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
        Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="leftContent" runat="server" ID="PageLeft">
        Page Left Contentt</asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="middleContent" runat="server" ID="PageMiddle">
        Page Middle Content</asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="rightContent" runat="server" ID="PageRight">
        Page Right Content</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Any reason why you changed for the page-left, right, middle to class instead of ID?

Comment: There is no reason behind it. I changed with id and modified css accordingly. Copy and paste in html file and check. It works for me!

Comment: Are you using master page? I tried not using master page and that works. It is only when I use the master page this thing fails.

Comment: Updated my html with master page code. It works for me. try that layout

Comment: Yeah, I tried that way and it works. Thank you. What I'm trying to figure out is why does the DIV with either ID or CLASS does not work in the content page. I mean later on, I might need to create other DIVs that need to flow even within those ContentPlaceHolders and I would have the same problem again.

Comment: I noticed something interesting. When I tried on Chrome and used the Inspect Element. It shows all the DIV tags in the Content page does not match any CSS stylesheet elements.

Comment: Check whether the CSS file is included properly by clicking on link node in chrome inspect element

Comment: Ah! Managed to solve it by renaming the site.css to site1.css . It all starts to work. Thank you Murali for being patient and helping me. So all along it was the browser that cached up the CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to set the width on your elements and you can lose the `clear: both` `<div>` and just put `overflow: hidden` on `pagemiddle`. (The height isn't needed, I just put it there to better illustrate my answer)

```
#pagemiddle { overflow: hidden; width: 500px; }
#pagemiddleleft { float: left; background-color: #FFFF00; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
#pagemiddlecenter { float: left; background-color: #00FFFF; width: 300px; height: 100px; }
#pagemiddleright { float: right; background-color: #FF00FF; width: 100px; height: 100px; }​
```

**Demo** - http://jsfiddle.net/8NH8t/

Comment: Guys, thank you for helping. I just want to highlight that if I were to do a simple HTML page with the DIV tags and the CSS file. I don't have any problems. It is only when I use the Visual Studio and use the Master Page that this problem occurs.